# Get a nested value with lodash

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

I'm trying to retrieve a nested value from an object by the given key. I've made it working with two simple `forEach` loops but I like to use a more... functional approach to this problem.

Here is the code I've got so far:

```
const object = {
  screen: {
    '[data-id="123"]': {
      'font-family': 'Arial',
    },
    '[data-id="456"]': {
      'background-color': 'red',
      'font-family': 'Comic Sans',
    },
  },
};

const prop = 'font-family';
const props = [];

forEach(object, (selectors) => {
  forEach(selectors, (selector) => {
    if (prop in selector) {
      props.push(selector[prop]);
    }
  });
});

console.log(props);
```

In this case, the function returns an array of font families (indicated by the `prop` const).

I'm looking to using lodash functions like `map` and `reduce` but I don't really know where to start.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is a nested object it would really depend on how you want to tackle this. If you use the map in a nested fashion, you will end up with a nested array. To match your output the nested array can be flattened.

```
_.flatten(_.map(object, (prop) => _.map(prop, (nestedProp) => nestedProp['font-family'])));
```

But if you don't want to use reduce instead of flatten then you could reduce the nested array from the array

```
_.reduce(_.map(object, (prop) => _.map(prop, (nestedProp) => nestedProp['font-family'])),(a, b) => [...a, ...b]);
```

At this point I think readability is taking some hit. As you can see nested map functions can get messy.

Comment: Given OP's code using nested loops (instead of targeting `object.screen` directly), I wonder if there may be other properties to consider as well.

Comment: Yes, there can other properties as well. Screen is just one of them. Therefore the nested loops.

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! The first option with flatten is indeed the most readable solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_.flatMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatMap) to recursively iterate an object/array, and collect all values with a key that equals the prop:

```js
const collect = (prop, obj) =>
  _.flatMap(obj, (v, k) => {
    if(k === prop) return v;
    
    return _.isObject(v) ? collect(prop, v) : [];
  });

const object = {
  screen: {
    '[data-id="123"]': {
      'font-family': 'Arial',
    },
    '[data-id="456"]': {
      'background-color': 'red',
      'font-family': 'Comic Sans',
    },
  },
};

const result = collect('font-family', object);

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

In vanilla JS you can use [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap):

```js
const collect = (prop, obj) =>
  Object.entries(obj).flatMap(([k, v]) => {
    if(k === prop) return v;
    
    return typeof v === 'object' && v !== null ? collect(prop, v) : [];
  });

const object = {
  screen: {
    '[data-id="123"]': {
      'font-family': 'Arial',
    },
    '[data-id="456"]': {
      'background-color': 'red',
      'font-family': 'Comic Sans',
    },
  },
};

const result = collect('font-family', object);

console.log(result);
```